# Dynamic call graphs in Haskell (or other higher order languages)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, call-graph

My question about dynamic call graphs is twofold:

First of all I am interested if there is any work that gives a definition for call graphs in higher order functional languages?

For example consider the following example program in Haskell:

```
f a b = a + b
g = f 1
h x = if x == "y" then g 3 else f 4 5
main = do 
  s <- getLine
  print (h s)
```

Is the g function a successor of h? This depends on the x-argument of the h-function: therefore we are looking for the dynamic call graph.

Assume x to be equal to "y". Is the f-function a successor of the g-function, of the h-function or of both? Or should we not consider f-function as a whole at all?

Clearly these questions call for a (formal) definition of a dynamic call graph. The definition that Sereni uses in their paper is helpful, but they are concerned with static rather than dynamic call graphs.

Secondly, are there tools to construct a dynamic call graph for Haskell? I am aware of SourceGraph. As far as I know this tool construct a static call graph, which is interesting too, but not what I am looking for.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it asks for off-site resources such as a library or tool, and because it's quite vague.  Could you provide the definition (or an example) of a call graph, possibly what you want to do with it, and a specific problem you've encountered while attempting to construct or manipulate them?  It sounds like you could try searching Hackage for an appropriate library (where most open source Haskell projects live), and google for an appropriate tool to solve your second problem.

Comment: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1291165 may be relevant